# Функция диалога из другого файла (котлин, аndroid)

Tags: android, kotlin

В MainActivity кнопка запускает код из другого файла

```kotlin
val btnExit: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnExit) as Button
btnExit.setOnClickListener {
   exitSid()
}
```

код из другого файла, имя пакета одинаковое

https://pastebin.com/embed/NaExjTDB

```java
fun exitSid() {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Закрыть программу")
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.appicon)
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Выйти из программы?")
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Выйти"){_,_ ->
        Toast.makeText(this,"exiting!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Нет"){_,_ ->
        Toast.makeText(this,"Вы не вышли из программы!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Cancel"){_,_ ->
        Toast.makeText(this,"Вы отменили выход из программы!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
}
```

Проблема: программа ругается на **this**

Comment: Сделайте из функции exitSid экстеншен-функцию: `fun Context.exitSid()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В языке Kotlin, так же как и в Java, `this` — это ссылка на текущий объект. Находясь внутри глобальной функции, никакого объекта нет, ссылаться на `this` не имеет смысла (кроме случая с экстеншен-функцией, см. ниже). Поэтому вы и получаете ошибку компиляции.

Многим сущностям в андроиде нужен контекст. [Почитайте](https://habr.com/ru/post/421115/), какие они бывают.

Как исправить ошибку? Два варианта:

1. Передать контекст как аргумент:

   ```kotlin
   fun exitSid(context: Context) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "exiting!", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
   ```

   Из активити можно вызвать так (активити является контекстом):

   ```kotlin
   exitSid(this)
   ```
2. Либо передать контекст как ресивер, то есть сделать функцию [экстеншен-функцией](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/extensions.html), тогда `this` снова обретет смысл:

   ```kotlin
   fun Context.exitSid() {
       Toast.makeText(this, "exiting!", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
   ```

   В этом случае из активити эта функция вызывается так:

   ```kotlin
   this.exitSid()
   ```

   Или просто:

   ```kotlin
   exitSid()
   ```

Comment: в статье написано _"Неправильное использование Context может легко привести к утечкам памяти в Android приложении."_ Поэтому какой из двух вариантов на ваш взгляд лучше? (и на всякий случай - у меня теперь алерт, а не тост)

Comment: Любой из способов, они отличаются только синтаксисом, как вам кажется выглядит более красиво, так и пишите. К утечкам не приведет, так как контекст никуда не сохраняем. Экстеншен-функции это фича языка котлин. В процессе компиляции ресивер по сути станет первым аргументом этой функции. Если в IDE выполнить "decompile kotlin to java", то в этом легко можно убедиться.

Comment: Для меня первый вариант более понятен - когда в качестве аргумента функции exitSid передаем (content: this). Но ваш второй пример как раз является extensions. А раз котлин надо значит его использовать ) А данном моем случае что расширяется класс или функция?

Comment: хочу все свои функции вынести в отдельный файл, поэтому и нужно выбрать правильный вариант, может там и переменные будут... которые будут оставаться в памяти.

Comment: Почитал также https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/extensions.html, но не понял как это применить к _"В большинстве случаев используйте контекст, доступный непосредственно из компонента, в котором вы работаете в данный момент. Вы можете безопасно хранить ссылку на него, если она не выходит за пределы жизненного цикла этого компонента. Как только вам нужно сохранить ссылку на контекст в объекте, который живет за пределами вашей Activity или другого компонента, даже временно, используйте ссылку на контекст приложения."_